# Apache Log Format adds quotes and backslash

Tags: apache, logging

In `httpd.conf` I've set the LogFormat to:

```
LogFormat "%t %{client-ip}i \"%{X-Forwarded-For}i\" %l %u \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" sessid=%{SESSID}C **guid=%{guid}C** req_guid=%{X-Hcom-Info}o" netscaler
```

The problem is with the way the guid cookie value gets logged: 
`guid=\"357ceacc-d2fb-458d-bc53-c6d1384d47dd:1107014198\"`

It adds \" \" around the guid - maybe because of the :1107014198 part.

How do i get apache to log the guid as:
`guid=357ceacc-d2fb-458d-bc53-c6d1384d47dd:1107014198`
i.e with out the \" \"

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not Apache that is adding the \"\" characters. The guid variable probably already has those. You need to figure out where the guid variable is being set and make sure it isn't quoted at that time.